# What effect does listing an internal social contact have, when applying for a job?

Tags: applications, networking

I've applied to a few jobs at one place recently, and one of the questions that is asked is whether I have a family contact or social relationship contact within their company.  I have a good friend there now, so they agreed to let me list them as my social contact.

I provided the name, title, and working group of my social contact, on the job application online.

What effect does this have on my application?  Would I typically be given preference?  Will my friend be contacted internally to help them evaluate my skills / personality?

This is the first job application in which I have encountered such a question, so I think it's interesting.

Comment: It also might be to make sure that some one you know Is not involved in the interviewing process.

Comment: What kind of job is it? There are some fields (finance, for example) where close relatives are kept apart in certain departments for risk/compliance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What effect does this have on my application? Would I typically be given preference? Will my friend be contacted internally to help them evaluate my skills / personality?

From experience your contact would be asked as any other reference would be if the rest of your CV looked positive for the role. There may also be a referral bonus for your contact, this is less prevalent in professional jobs though.

One positive thing about it is that in small locales a known and easily contactable person as a reference is much preferable to an unknown. In my own country a referral from an unknown person is just worth the toner used to print it.